# I want to fetch data date wise

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to fetch `data` `$form` to `$to` variable which has date stored in it. so basicaly I want to fetch the `data date wise`.

Here is my code:

```
if ($_POST['data'] == 'paymentanalyticdata') {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->join = 'LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_integration AS PI ON PI.name = t.payment_method AND PI.store_id=' . Yii::app()->session['store_id'];
    $criteria->select = 'PI.title as payment_method,sum(t.total) as total';
    $criteria->group = 'PI.title';
    $criteria->condition = 't.store_id=\'' . Yii::app()->session['store_id'] . '\'';

    $from = isset($_POST['from']) ? $_POST['from'] : '';
    $to = isset($_POST['to']) ? $_POST['to'] : '';
    if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
        $criteria->condition .= 't.entrydate';
    }
    $list = Order::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $categorylist = [];
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $categorylist[] = array('PI' => $row->payment_method, 'total' => $row->total);
    }

    $seocount['paymentanalyticdata'] = $categorylist;
    echo json_encode($seocount);
```

I want to write condition in

```
$criteria->condition .='????';
```

What code should be write  in this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `addCondition`, something like:

```
if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
    $criteria->addCondition('t.entrydate >= :startDate AND t.entrydate <= :endDate');
    $criteria->params = array(':startDate' => $from, ':endDate' => $to);
}
```

or, by using `addBetweenCondition`:

```
if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
   $criteria->addBetweenCondition("entrydate", $from, $to);
}
```

Comment: thank you but i want to use conditation only and what shoud i write in <pre>$criteria->condition .='????';</pre> what i can replace on ?????

Comment: @KevinPatel you're welcome, if it has helped you please do accept the answer.

Comment: I AM NEW ON STACKOVERFLOW SO I SNT KNW HOW TO ACCEPT ANSWER SO PLEASE CAN U TELL ME HOW TO ACCEPT ANSWER???? @Criesto

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `between` like that :-

```
$f=$_POST['from'];
$t=$_POST['to']
$criteria->condition .= 't.entrydate BETWEEN $f and $t';
```

Comment: can you plz print MySQL query and past in comment

Comment: How?  I cant understood u.

Comment: **echo** your MySQL query

Answer (score 0):

using addBetweenCondition:

```
      if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
      $criteria->addBetweenCondition("entrydate", $from, $to);
 }
```